# gsl lu decomposition and inversion for float matrix

Tags: gsl

Due to memory limit, I need to use `gsl_matrix_float` instead of `gsl_matrix` which stores data of type double. However, I want to use `gsl_linalg_LU_decomp` and `gsl_linalg_LU_invert` which only support `gsl_matrix`. And I did not find some other method which support the float version decomposition and inversion in gsl.

Is there any way to solve this dilemma? Or I can only transfer from float to double and then back? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe there is only support for double precision for GSL, as is stated here https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Long-double.html

Answer (score 0):

The best you can probably do is, as you suggest, convert from float to double and back. Here is example code to perform the inversion (only the essential components are given - you have to fill in the blanks):

```
include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>

void matrix_invert(gsl_matrix_float *, gsl_matrix_float *, int);

int main()
{
 gsl_matrix_float *X = gsl_matrix_float_alloc(N, N);
 gsl_matrix_float *invX = gsl_matrix_float_alloc(N, N);

 matrix_invert(X, invX, N); //invM = inv(I)
 return 0;
}

void matrix_invert(gsl_matrix_float *matrix, gsl_matrix_float *inverse, int N)
{
 int i=0,j=0,signum=0;
 gsl_matrix *DM = gsl_matrix_alloc(N, N);
 gsl_matrix *DM_I = gsl_matrix_alloc(N, N);

 for (i=0;i<N;i++)
  for (j=0;j<N;j++)
   gsl_matrix_set(DM, i, j, gsl_matrix_float_get(matrix,i,j));

  gsl_permutation *p = gsl_permutation_alloc(N);
  gsl_linalg_LU_decomp(DM, p, &signum);
  gsl_linalg_LU_invert(DM, p, DM_I);
  gsl_permutation_free(p);
  gsl_matrix_free(DM);

  for (i=0;i<N;i++)
   for (j=0;j<N;j++)
    gsl_matrix_float_set(inverse, i, j, gsl_matrix_get(DM_I,i,j));
}
```